# DJI iOS SDK 4.7 add so many bin files

Tags: dji-sdk

I noticed that in the commit a6e2288 on 30 Aug in the repository Mobile-SDK-iOS of dji-sdk, it add a lot of bin files in the Sample Code/ObjcSampleCode/DJISdkDemo/Resource directory. And I found that those files names are only appeared in the DJIWidget project by searching the file name. Therefore according to this commit, there are two things confused me.

Firstly, I wonder if I need put those files in my swift application which only uses the swift version of DJI SDK since those files only add in ObjcSampleCode directory. To be honest, I don't know much about Objective-C.

Moreover, I found that there is no such commit in the Mobile-UXSDK-iOS repository. So dose it need this commit as well?

By the way, the code of DUXSDK in previous version such as 4.6 use a bundle file to manage those images that are used in the VideoPreviewer project. Why those images are added into project directly in version 4.7? I am not very familiar with the file structures in Xcode project and can someone explain to me?

Answer (score 1):

Those bin files are for Mavic 2 decode image distortion calibrate. The reason why those files only add in ObjcSampleCode directory is SwiftSampleCode is not supporting DJIWidget features.

Mobile-UXSDK-iOS is still not supporting this feature now. Will coming next release.

The reason why we add the bin files as resource file is it's used by DJIWidget and the bin files import in the application project. If we used a resource bundle we need to add it to DJIWidget.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I would like to response about your answer to my last question. You said that because you don't want to add those bin files into DJIWidget. I agree with that. However, I think it would be more convenient for DJI SDK users to upgrade SDK version if you pack those files into one bundle.

Comment: Another thing is that I noticed that in the DJIWidget project, the codes is look for resources all from the main bundle which is different from version 4.6. I guess this is one reason why you don't use bundle file.

In my opinion, you may look for bundles from a specific file path and pack those bin files into a bundle file.

Again, thanks for your response.

Comment: @NuoyuanYan Thanks for your suggestion. Updated Sample code and DJIWidget implementation.